# Problem with axios interceptor : .then is always triggered after .catch (Vue Js + Laravel API)

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, axios, interceptor

I'm currently facing a big problem. I'm working on a VueJS front-end (located inside Laravel's resources folder) combined with a Laravel API. As you cas guess, I have plenty of API calls (with axios) in my vue component. I'm using pinia for my stores.

To clean up my code and simplify errors managing, I have added an axios interceptor inside bootstrap.js file (code sample below). Therefore, I removed all the .catch blocks of all my axios API calls.

```
import { useUserStore } from "./stores/userStore"

axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) { return response },
    function (error) {
        console.log("fonction error de l'interceptor"); // displayed
        console.log(error.response); // displayed properly too

        if (error.response.data.errors) { // data.errors = validation errors ("username is too long"...)
            const userStore = useUserStore()
            userStore.storeErrors(error.response.data.errors) // stores the errors
            // return Promise.reject(error.response);
            // throw error;
        }
        else if (error.response.message) {
            alert(error.response.message) // for cases without form validation errors
        }
        else { // all the other cases without specific messages
            alert("Une erreur s'est produite. Certains éléments peuvent ne pas être affichés. Vous pouvez essayer de recharger la page pour corriger le problème.")
        }
    });
```

Inside the if block, I'm storing form validation errors in my userstore (if there are some). These errors are automatically deleted every time the route changes, with a beforeach guard added in my vue-router file (router.js).

My problem is that, when I pass inside the function(error) of the interceptor (e.g when there are mistakes noticed by Laravel validator when I fill a form), I then always pass inside the .then block of EVERY API call, and I get an error like "response is not defined" (because the .then block always uses the response to do something).

I've tried to add in my function(error) of the interceptor (the commented lines) :

- Promise.reject(error) / Promise.reject(error.response) => gives an "error 400" inside the console
- throw error => same result

On all the form components, the error messages are correctly displayed. The validation errors are correctly saved inside the userStore. So no visible problem fo the user, but I don't want to leave any error in the console before building for production.

Any help would be appreciated. I can provide any other code sample needed.
Thanks guys.

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. The question doesn't contain code that uses this interceptor

Comment: if you "handle" the error in a `.catch` then of course the next `.then` will execute - see how you commented out `return Promise.reject(error.response);` ... that's how you make sure the error propagates ...by returning a rejection, or throwing an error, both of which you've commented out .... this is Promises 101 stuff